# Xamarin.Forms make WebView editable

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

Is it possible to make WebView from Xamarin.Forms editable? Or there is any ready made rich editor which can edit a simple html? What I need is to display and edit text that have bold text in it, bullets, ets.

Comment: there are numerous JS based rich text editors you could try loading in a embedded webview.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: @Tanya, Don't know if the HybridWebView can require your need:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally find this question and it has a link to a good editor, that is free and lightweight.
[How to create a Rich Text box with or without web view in xamarin forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070344/how-to-create-a-rich-text-box-with-or-without-web-view-in-xamarin-forms)